# How to extend a string in awk

Tags: awk

I need to add dashes (`-`) to the end of a string in `awk`. The number of dashes is dynamic (it can be anything from 0 to like 1024), so it cannot be hard-coded. How to achieve it in `awk`?

In can be implemented like this:

```
function gen_chars(N) { s=""; for (i=1;i<=N; i++) {s = s "-"}; return s; }
```

but it looks ugly

Comment: and where is your input text and expected output?

Comment: And how do you determine the number of dashes to add?

Answer (score 0):

create a long pad with the desired char and cut the required length, for example

```
awk -v size=5 'BEGIN {s="-"; for(i=1;i<=10;i++) s=s s; 
                      print "string" substr(s,1,size)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative with gnu awk:

```
$ cat file5
home
help

$ awk -vnd="15" '{$(NF+1)=sprintf("%*s",nd,"-");gsub(/[ ]/,"-",$NF)}1' file5   #nd=number of dashes
home ---------------
help ---------------
```

Another alternative would be to have a text/var with the maximum dashes (i.e 1024) and using printf to limit the max width:

```
$ md=$(printf '%.s-' {1..1024})   #md=max dashes = 1024
$ awk -vmd=$md -vnd="15" '{printf "%s%.*s\n",$0,nd,md}' file5    #nd=size of dashes
home---------------
help---------------
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
awk '
function gen_chars(n) { return gensub(/ /,"-","g",sprintf("%*s",n,"")) }
BEGIN { print gen_chars(3) }
'
---
```

with other awks:

```
function gen_chars(n,   s) { s=sprintf("%*s",n,""); gsub(/ /,"-",s); return s }
```